# How to order the indices in a list with R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list where my items correspond to matrices. Each itemname looks like this `$test_parallel_1.RData` until `$test_parallel_10.RData` . I would like to order numerically the itemnames, because `$test_parallel_10.RData` comes just after `$test_parallel_1.RData` . And `$test_parallel_9.RData` is at the end of the list..

Bests, Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try gtools package

```
> install.packages("gtools") ## install gtools
> library(gtools)            ## load package
> mixedsort(your_list)       ## this will sort as expected
```

For sorting the list with names, use the following code:-

```
> your_list <- your_list[mixedsort(names(your_list))]
```

Comment: I get an error message : "> mixedsort(results)
Error in order(x, decreasing = decreasing, na.last = na.last) : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'"

Comment: use `your_list <- your_list[mixedsort(names(your_list))]` in order to sort the list by the element names
`